# Y position while composing a PdfPTable

Tags: itext

I'm building a pdfptable thru ItextSharp, but I need to know, while I'm adding cells, my Y position in the page. Cells have a variable height.
I need to know it to avoid tu put a new 'Breaking title' in the table if this would go on the last table row, as it should go on a new page (on cust request). 
I tried writer.getverticalPosition() but it seems not reliable in composing a table.

Is there a way to know it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a contradiction in your question. Let me explain what doesn't make sense.

You create a `PdfPTable`, let say you have an object named `table`. when you add cells to `table`, the object grows. Plenty of data is stored into memory.

Now you say: I want to know the Y position of the rows on the page while I'm adding cells.

Which page? There may not even be a page? As long as you build the `table` object, there is no page, there are no Y positions. One table could be 200pt heigh when added to a page with a width of 400pt. *The same table* could be 400pt heigh when added to a page with a width of 200pt. It isn't until you add the `table` object to a `Document` that the table gets its shape.

If you want to make sure a "title" isn't the last row on a page, you should break up your table in smaller parts. Create a subtable and add it to the document. Now use `getVerticalPosition()` and check how much space is left. If there isn't sufficient space for the first X rows of the next subtable, move to a `newPage()` and add the next table there, otherwise add the table on the current page.

If you define the widths correctly, nobody will see that you've been adding more than one table: it will look as if you added one large table instead of different small ones. If you don't know how to calculate the height of the rows in the subtables, please note that you need to define the total width of the table and lock the widths. For the reason explaiined above, no software can calculate the height of a table if it doesn't have any info about its width.

Comment: anyone any Ideas on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611876/itext-sharp-i-cannot-align-my-table-to-the-left-of-the-page