# I cannot align my table to the left of the page?

Tags: c#, itext

I have created a PDF but the image is appearing to the middle of the page and I cannot figure out how to align the image and the cell of text to the left of the page.

This is my code

```
PdfWriter.GetInstance(mydoc, New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))

mydoc.Open()

Dim titleTable As New Table(2, 1)
titleTable.Border = 0
titleTable.BorderWidth = 0
titleTable.Cellpadding = 3
titleTable.SetWidths({20, 80})
titleTable.DefaultCellBorder = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER
titleTable.TableFitsPage = True

Dim myCell As Cell

'add impero logo 
Dim imperoImage As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(GetBytesForImage(<my image>))
imperoImage.ScalePercent(15)
myCell = New iTextSharp.text.Cell(imperoImage)
myCell.SetHorizontalAlignment(Cell.ALIGN_LEFT)
titleTable.AddCell(myCell)

'title
Dim myChunk As New iTextSharp.text.Chunk(ImperoClientApp.LanguageResources.GetPhrase("some text", Nothing), _
    iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont(iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.HELVETICA, 16, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, New iTextSharp.text.Color(0, 0, 0)))
myCell = New iTextSharp.text.Cell(myChunk)
myCell.VerticalAlignment = iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE
titleTable.AddCell(myCell)
mydoc.Add(titleTable)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you turn your table borders back on you'll see that the table cell is as far left as the table allows:

```
titleTable.Border = 1
titleTable.BorderWidth = 1
''//titleTable.DefaultCellBorder = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER
```

[image]

But you also need to tell the table to take up as much horizontal space as possible:

```
titleTable.Width = 100
```

[image]

However, all of this will still be relative to the document's size *including* margins. Depending on what you're doing you could just remove the margins from the document completely when you create it:

```
Dim Doc As New Document(PageSize.LETTER, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

[image]

**NOTE!**

The `iTextSharp.text.Table` is very old and has been unsupported for almost a decade. Instead you are encouraged to use `iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable`. Almost all documentation out there will always be about the `PdfPTable`. Upgrading your code shouldn't be too painful as they have mostly similar methods and properties.

Comment: Thanks @Bruno, sorry for not putting that first!